# Clone Login\User in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2017 database instance that was created before I was given administration of the database and I have a Login at DB server level named "atSupervisor" which is a user in database "StaffMonitoring".  I wish to clone the login and user "atSupervisor" as login and user "bcSupervisor" in database "StaffMonitoring" to have all permissions, table access, grants etc.

I have tried a few suggestions on google such as this example - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3589/how-to-clone-a-sql-server-login-part-1-of-3/

This seems to creates the login and user and I can then assign the database "StaffMonitoring" in User Mapping in the login's properties and login with the user.  However, none of the tables are present.

Is there a way to do this please that clones everything to include grant access to tables that mirrors the original login\user?

Comment: That article is part one in a three part series and deals only with server-level permissions. Part two deals with database-level permissions and part three says "but what if twenty databases??". As long as you're at it, I'd recommend migrating all of the permissions for atSupervisor into a user-defined database role to make operations like this easier in the future (and to prevent drift between atSupervisor and bcSupervisor).